# Shared error view in ASP.Net MVC 3, what's it for?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm still new to MVC 3 and I'm struggling to create a nice error page for my application.

I've noticed the shared Error.cshtml view which is auto generated, what's it used for and how ?

Any links to implementing a simple single error page would be brilliant as well :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is already in place; you just aren't seeing it as **by default** raw errors are displayed if your request comes from the web-server itself - very useful for debugging. Remote visitors would see the default error.cshtml result:

> Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.

To see the error page even when local, ensure the customErrors mode is "On":

```
<customErrors mode="On"/>
```

You may need to add this to `<system.web>` in web.config. But most commonly during debugging this is set to "RemoteOnly".

Comment: +1 Ah stupid me, I'm so used to WebForms I had added DefaultRedirect="/Error". You're right, it works automatically when just set to On. Thanks :-)

Comment: a bit more complicated if you need to do something before to shwo the error page, for example if you need to send and email with the error log.

Comment: @Bugeo there are controller methods and global hooks for that, too

Comment: @MarcGravell it's showing me a standard "The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by ..." YSOD. What am I missing?

Comment: @ashes999 maybe follow the "by..." instructions?

Comment: @MarcGravell your post seems to say that *by default* you should see /Shared/Error.cshtml if you set `customErrors mode="On"`. I did that, and I don't see the error page; setting `defaultRedirect` to `~/Error` doesn't help, either...

Comment: @ashes999 I've just validated in a new web-project; **all** I need to do to see the error cshtml is add: `<customErrors mode="On"/>` under `<system.web>`. You might want to check you aren't being affected by `Web.Debug.config`/`Web.Release.config`

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm definitely not seeing it, without the two specific config files. It's strange; it worked once, then stopped. I resorted to using a custom controller and views for now. Cheers though.